# foreach not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am currently new to database query and other for codeigniter can not seem to quite get model working for what I am after.

I have tried loading db in direct to controller and that works OK. But if I call my model does not want to work nothing shows up.

Here is what I would like to achieve.

**Controller**

```
public function website_test_model() {

    $this->load->model('admin/website/model_website');

    $results = $this->model_website->getWebsites();

    $data['websites'] = array();

        foreach ($results as $result) {
            $data['websites'] = array(
                'website_id' => $result['website_id'],
                'name' => $result['name'],
                'url' => $result['url']
            );
        }

    $this->load->view('website/websites', $data);
   }
```

**View**

```
<!-- Not Working From Controller Function Model Test -->

<?php if ($websites) { ?>
<?php foreach ($websites as $website) { ?>

<?php echo $website['website_id'];?>

<br>

<?php echo $website['name'];?>

<br>

<?php echo $website['url'];?>

<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

**Model**

```
<?php

class Model_website extends CI_Model {

  function getWebsites() {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('website');
      $this->db->where('website_id');
      $this->db->where('name');
      $this->db->where('url');
      $query = $this->db->get();

      if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->row();
      } else {
        return false;
      }
  }


}
```

Codeigniter Demo It works when I try it this way as said on codeigniter User Guide. Just the code above is way I am after though Trying to make model work no luck

```
public function website() {

    $results = $this->db->get('website'); // Works Direct From Controller OK.

        foreach ($results->result() as $row) {
            $data = array(
                'website_id' => $row->website_id,
                'name' => $row->name,
                'url' => $row->url
            );
        }

    $this->load->view('website/website', $data);
   }
```

Comment: try to do print_r($results) before assigning it to $data['website']

Comment: Just refresh page and now  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: @acoderslife because `$results` is returning false;

Comment: @acoderslife check your query to enable profiler, make sure all your where conditions working fine, because it is different `$results = $this->db->get('website');` then your model query.

Comment: Done that nothing showing up on profiler but error Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: man....your where conditions are not proper you are not comparing the field with anything.. how come you will get a result..

Comment: Well, `$data['websites']` should probably be `$data['websites'][]`. You should also throw in an `if` statement to check that `$results` is not `false`. Most of the time when people have problems where stuff does not work as expected it is because they are not checking that values are what they expect them to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are doing wrong in you model file

```
<?php

class Model_website extends CI_Model {

  function getWebsites() {
       $query =$this->db->get('website');

      if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->result();
      } 
  }


}
```

1) In your model you are using where condition but `$this->db->where('website_id');` but you not passing anything in your condition you have to do like this `$this->db->where('website_id',$yourwebsite_id);`

Answer (score 0):

You have to check db query in model it's return result or not.

use this query in model

```
 $this->db->last_query();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this query in model

```
$query = $this->db->get('website');
return $query;
```

Pass this query to view then use this foreach

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
    <?php echo $row->website_id; ?>
    <br>
    <?php echo $row->name;?>
    <br>
    <?php echo $row->url;?>

}
```